# How to send a javascript file (with several functions in it) from the server to the client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, html

I need to have the functionality in the server side in order to hide the implementetion to the final user. 
I didn't find a topic with this kind of solution.

I have a .js file with functions I use within the html5 file. 
The js files are "called" in the html by using the script tag, but through the url the user can track them and see the .js file content. I don't want this to happen.
$getScript() does the job, but again the url can be cathched, thus the file content too. Much the same with $ajax function.
Everything work ok, but I want to hide the js content.

The .js file is something like this:

```
var x, x,....

function A(){...}
function B(){...}
```

and so on, I use A(), B() functions in the html.

Which is the best approach to get the content file from the server without doing the url visible?

Server: nodejs. (I send some json files through socket.io correctly, but I don't know how to achieve this other issue.

Thanks in advance, best!

Comment: There is no way to prevent a user seeing something that the browser can see. None. If you have secret stuff you don't want the client to see, do that processing at serverside. I.e. instead of calling `A` on client, invoke an AJAX call that will invoke `A` at server.

Comment: Cannot do it, sockets are still visible. Chrome dev tools has a socket tab

Comment: @Amadan do you have an example of an AJAX call of a function? thanks

Comment: @JuanMendes thanks for the advice. So, what is the best practice to call a function from the server?

Comment: Just make a node express route that implements your function; you can invoke it using `$.ajax` if you're using jQuery.

Comment: @rossig like Amadan said, hide it behind an AJAX call

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending sensitive information to the client then you are doing it wrong. No matter if the client has the URL to the script, they will still be able to find it if they are determined as long as it is sent to their computer.

Find a different way to accomplish what you are trying to do without sending sensitive information to the client. It is not safe.

Comment: I am aware of that that's why I am asking a clue of doing it correctly, avoiding it from the client view.